# Why my android react native app crashes outside my country?

Tags: android, react-native

I have an app who built with react native for android and iOS...
I know the app is available only in United States, I mean that for iOS you can get the app from every country but for android you can't get it if your store isn't connect to United States store... from some reason only with android, when I downloaded the app(with vpn) in other country outside United States the app is working but after Im trying to logged in(put my username, password and press log in) the app crashes, the app is working on android in United States and not crashes and the problem isn't happening at all with iOS...
when I review the logs in the server I can see that all the endpoints that suppose to happens after logged in succeed.

what might be the problem? the error i'm getting that the app has stopped..it could be a problem with auth?

Thank you for the help

adding my androidmanifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xx"
android:versionCode="10"
android:versionName="1.0.9">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <service
    android:name=".FirebaseServices.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <service
    android:name=".FirebaseServices.FirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
</application>
```

Comment: add crash analytics in your app and check this logs